# When insert rows using python psycopg2, docker postgres process is terminated

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, memory, docker

Database is postgresql-9.5.1 in docker. My host machine has 3.75 GB memory, linux. In some methods I am inserting 490000 rows one after another using psycopg2 with below code.

```
student_list = [(name, surname, explanation)]
args_str = ','.join(cur.mogrify("(%s,%s,%s)", x) for x in student_list)
cur.execute('INSERT INTO students (name, surname, explanation) VALUES ' + args_str)
```

This makes my database docker memory seems full and gives these errors:

> LOG:  server process (PID 11219) was terminated by signal 9:
>   Killed
>  DETAIL:  Failed process was running
>  LOG:  terminating
>   any other active server processes
>  docker@test_db WARNING: 
>   terminating connection because of crash of another server process
>   docker@test_db DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server
>   process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another
>   server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared
>   memory.
>  docker@test_db HINT:  In a moment you should be able to
>   reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
>  docker@test_db
>   WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server
>   process
>  docker@test_db DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this
>   server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because
>   another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared
>   memory.
>  ... docker@test_db FATAL:  the database system is in
>   recovery mode
>  LOG:  all server processes terminated;
>   reinitializing
>  LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known
>   up at 2017-06-06 09:39:40 UTC
>  LOG:  database system was not
>   properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
>  docker@test_db
>   FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
>  docker@test_db
>   FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
>  docker@test_db
>   FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
>  LOG:  autovacuum
>   launcher started

Script gives that log:

> Inner exception
>   SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected

I tried put some sleep time between consecutive queries but got same result. Is there any limitation for that?
Also I tried to connect and disconnect for each query but got same result. These are my connect and disconnect methods.

```
def connect():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database=database_name,
                            user=database_user,
                            host=database_host,
                            port=database_port)
    conn
  .set_isolation_level(psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    return conn, cur

def disconnect(conn, cur):
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Are you passing some custom memory command to `docker run`?

Comment: No, just docker run command

Comment: Check the `dmesg` command in your host. It is probably some *out of memory* problem. You should see there that Postgres is being killed.

Comment: Are you running docker directly in your host, or are you using docker-machine?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did. Actually my memory was full enough. That's why linux OS used to kill the process in Postgresql. There were 1M values in every insert process. The trick was I divided data lists to chunks and tried it 100k by 100k. That works very well. Thanks for your helps.